# What font is used for this 85 years logo?

Tags: font-identification

I would like to know what font is used for the numbers in the following designs. I would like to use the same style for a design that I'm doing. I have tried identifying it using:

- [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)
- [Matcherator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator)

But they did not return accurate results.

I'm 100% sure that it is a font and not drawn by hand. I've reached out to the designer of the image but haven't received a response as yet.

I found the images [here](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/279082508141704592/). Any help to point me in the right direction would be great.

[image]

Comment: you should ask the creators of the logo http://shinyrocketdesign.com/portfolio/royal-college-of-physicians-and-surgeons-of-canada/

Comment: Your examples aren't the same. There are subtle differences in the number fives. My guess is that it isn't a font, but a custom designed logo. Not everything is a font.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WhatTheFont had trouble with the first example image, but gave me the correct font as a result when using the (now removed) [second example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPelM.jpg)...

#### [Colonna](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/colonna-mt/)

[image]

A few things to note...

It would be relatively easy to trace over the glyphs in the first image (so you have a clear black on white image), separating each number in the process. WhatTheFont would most likely then have identified the font.

Since each glyph is made up of distinct separate parts you need to combine them (by dragging one on to the other) when selecting the character mappings on WhatTheFont; otherwise it doesn't really know what it is searching for.

It's also worth noting that it looks like your example could be an italic version of the font, but it is actually just the angle of the camera (it's not clear from your example image, but in the original un-cropped version you can see [it is a photograph taken at an angle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0u8q.png))

Comment: I had already contacted the designer and received a response with the name of the font. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Nxlevel if this answer is the correct one, please mark it as accepted. Otherwise write an answer with the correct font name, so we can close this question - it helps with the website stats.